# Should I check third-parties submitting EVUS?

Tags: visas, usa

When I was reviewing my EVUS enrollment online, I was asked to check the boxes for something like terms and conditions. The second box is optional which says "I hereby certify that I have read to the enrollee all the questions and statements in this enrollment. I further certify that the enrollee understands all the questions and statements on this enrollment. The answers and information furnished in this enrollment are true and correct to the best of the enrollee's knowledge and belief". Should I check it?

[image]

Comment: Are you the enrollee or a 3rd party?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only check one box; they are mutually exclusive.

Are you, the person filling out the form, also the traveler?

If yes, then you check the first box.

If no, then the person who is filling out the form for you checks the second box.